# How to fetch the contact details from recepient_ids in threads table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

This is the 'threads' table instance

```
_id| recipient_ids| snippet
1  |   1          |Hi this is hello world
2  |   2          |Multiple send
3  | 1 3 4        |Send
```

The values corresponding to the recepient_ids are placed in 'canonical_addresses' table

```
_id|  address
1  |9879565655
2  |1111111111
3  |5465321348
4  |8965321354
```

Now i have to fetch the 'canonical_addresses.address' for each 'threads.recipient_ids' present in threads table (At times recipient_ids can be more than one) ?

Note:
I'm using `content://mms-sms/conversation` to fetch details from threads table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt find a direct solution towards it.

Indeed, in order to get the recipient details query `Content://sms/` with the thread id.

select distinct address from the cursor.

We will be able to get the recipient details.

For more efficient ways pls respond to it.

The snippet is as follows

```
Uri THREAD_ID_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uribuilder.build(), new String[]{"address"},"thread_id=#) group by (address", null,null);
```

Thank u

Comment: This approach fails on threads with only mms messages.  Not that I have a better answer...

Answer (score 2):

you need to formulate the query as per the below:

```
String [] colAddress={"DISTINCT address"};
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, colAddress, null, null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this uri for fetching

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
            Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), new String[]{"address"},
            "_id" + " = ?",
            new String[]{your_thread_id}, null);

    String contactAddress = null;

    if (pCur != null) {
        if (pCur.getCount() != 0) {
            pCur.moveToNext();
            contactAddress = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        }
        pCur.close();
    }
```